# What is the analytic expression for PDF of joint distribution of two Gaussian random vectors?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with respective PDFs,

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_x^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{\left(x-\mu_x\right)^2}{2\sigma_x^2}\right\} \\
f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_y^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{\left(y-\mu_y\right)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right\}
$$

Then their joint PDF is written as

$$
f_{XY}(x,y) =
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_x \sigma_y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
      \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2} -
          \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2}
        \right]
      \right)
$$

But when $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are random vectors with PDFs

$$
f_{\mathbf x}(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\, =
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{k/2}|\boldsymbol\Sigma_x|^{1/2}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu_x})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma_x}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu_x})
\right) \\
f_{\mathbf y}(y_1,\ldots,y_k)\, =
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{k/2}|\boldsymbol\Sigma_y|^{1/2}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({\mathbf y}-{\boldsymbol\mu_y})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma_y}^{-1}({\mathbf y}-{\boldsymbol\mu_y})
\right)
$$

How do you express their joint PDF?

$$
f_{\mathbf xy}(\mathbf {x,y})\, = \, ?
$$

Comment: Assuming _independence_?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian variables, then you don't know that $(X,Y)$ is a two-dimensional Gaussian vector.

Comment: Relevant [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent) from wikipedia, explaining Stefan's comment.

Comment: @Sasha No, I'm not assuming independence or being uncorrelated.

Comment: @hkBattousai: Then your initial example is wrong. Just by stating $f_X$ and $f_Y$ as Gaussian densities, you do not know that their joint PDF is of the form you write.

Comment: @StefanHansen you are right. First we need to know if they are jointly Gaussian, then marginals are Gaussian. But we can assume Jointly Gaussian random vectors, where no indep. is assumed.

Comment: I changed \operatorname{exp} to \exp.

Comment: I think one should not use the same notation to refer both to the random variable itself and the argument to the density function.  I would often use $\mathbf{X}$ for the random variable and $\mathbf{x}$ for the argument to the density or to a cdf.

Answer (score 7):

In the case where you only assume that $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are marginally Gaussian, you can't say much about the joint density of $(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y})$, and you certainly can't conclude that the joint density is a Gaussian density. In the answer below I've added the additional assumption that the joint distribution *is* indeed Gaussian.

Assume that $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_k)\sim\mathcal{N}_k(\boldsymbol{\mu}_x,\mathbf{\Sigma}_x)$ and $\mathbf{Y}=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_k)\sim\mathcal{N}_k(\boldsymbol{\mu}_y,\mathbf{\Sigma}_y)$ **and** that $\mathbf{Z}=(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y})$ follows a Gaussian distribution, then the joint density is given by
$$
f_\mathbf{Z}(\mathbf{z})=
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{2k/2}|\boldsymbol\Sigma_z|^{1/2}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({\mathbf z}-{\boldsymbol\mu_z})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma_z}^{-1}({\mathbf z}-{\boldsymbol\mu_z})
\right),\quad\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{R}^{2k},
$$
where
$$
\boldsymbol{\mu_z}=(\boldsymbol{\mu}_x,\boldsymbol{\mu}_y)
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{\Sigma}_z=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{\Sigma}_x & \mathbf{\Sigma}_{xy} \\
\mathbf{\Sigma}_{yx} & \mathbf{\Sigma}_y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
written in block form. Here $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{xy}$ is the $k\times k$ matrix whose $(i,j)$th entry is $$
\mathbf{\Sigma}_{xy}^{i,j}=\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,Y_j).
$$

Note that this also holds when $\mathbf{X}$ is $k$-dimensional and $\mathbf{Y}$ is $n$-dimensional for $n\neq k$.

Comment: What does $\boldsymbol{\mu_z}=(\boldsymbol{\mu}_x,\boldsymbol{\mu}_y)$ mean? Did you mean $\mathbf{\mu_z} = [\mathbf{\mu_x}^T \; \mathbf{\mu_y}^T]^T$?

Comment: If $\boldsymbol{\mu}_x$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}_y$ are column vectors, then yes.

Comment: I'd add that the answer above is correct ONLY if you assume joint normality of $(x,y)$.  Nothing about the joint, as opposed to marginal, distributions was mentioned in the question.  That's a gap that should be mentioned in any answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I did actually mention this in my answer (in fact it's emphasized by a bold "and"). Also, in the comments to the question I already mentioned that you cannot say anything in general about the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ given just the marginals.

Comment: @StefanHansen : But you didn't say explicitly that the question doesn't mention joint normality.  I'd have mentioned that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: You're right. I added something to the answer, thanks :)